# Why the async() function can still block the main thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading

```
void print2(){
    std::chrono::milliseconds timespan(10000);
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(timespan);
    cout<<"async"<<endl;
}
void print(){
    cout<<"bbb----"<<endl;
}
void test() {
    std::shared_ptr<void> _(nullptr, [&](...){ print(); });
    auto a = async(print2); //Modified: same result if use std::launch::async
    cout<<"end of test"<<endl;
    return;
}

int main()
{
    test();
    cout<<"going end of main"<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I run it here: https://onlinegdb.com/C6lymlHOJ

The result is always:

```
end of test
async
bbb----
going end of main
```

The main thread seems blocked so `"bbb---- "` and `"going end of main"` are printed at the end.

I tried ChatGPT and I think it was wrong, because it thinks the order of the printed log will likely be as follows:

```
end of test
going end of main
async
bbb----
```

Why is `async` blocking the main thread?

Comment: The clear answer in the manual of `std::future a`: [`std::future<T>::~future`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future/~future).

Comment: Remember that ChatGPT can't program and does not know C++. All it knows is how to string tokens together in a manner convincing to humans. It rarely manages to convince compilers to produce the desired program behaviour.

Comment: Using `std::async` without a launch policy also means that you let the implementation choose between `std::launch::async` and `std::launch::deferred` where `deferred` means that the task is executed **on the calling thread** when the result is requested. You probably don't want surprises so it's probably wise to choose one of these yourself.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Thanks Ted! But still the same result if I use async(std::launch::async..)

Comment: The destructor of `a` blocks until the task finishes running.

Comment: Also ChatGPT is trained on publicly visible code, most of which isn't all that great either.

Comment: tip : sleeps are blocking a lot too `std::this_thread::sleep_for(timespan);`  so your program cannot respond quickly if you have them in mainloops. Have a look at std::condition_variable::wait_for method so you can abort sleeping sooner when program shutsdown (or your task needs to be aborted).

Comment: @Michael My point is that you probably want to control if it should start running in the background or not. If your implementation has chosen `deferred`, you wouldn't even have seen the output `async`.